# generate wireframe plot with mplot3d Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, mplot3d

I have this data :

```
69120 40859 258
69219 40860 255
69319 40862 228
....
69519 40865 263
69619 40867 266
69719 40869 261
```

It's the positions of points in a 3D graph (X,Y,Z), called a filiation of points

I have multiple filiations :

```
69120 41459 249
69219 41460 262
69319 41462 262
...
69719 41469 263
69819 41471 263
69919 41472 264
```

I would like to create a wireframes graph with mplot3d  like this image but i don't what to put in X, Y, Z matrixs

[image: exemple of wireframes graph]

Thanks very much.

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: It's not a question of will. You **have to** put in matrices for `X`,`Y`,`Z`. Apart from that the question is really unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the documentation [mplot3d tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots) X, Y and Z are 2D-arrays, not matrices. Assuming the columns in your data correspond to X, Y and Z you could do the following:

```
X = [[69120, 69219, 69319], [69120, 69219, 69319]]
Y = [[40859, 40860, 40862],  [41459, 41460, 41462]]
Z = [[258, 255, 228], [249, 262, 262]]
```

So one set of your data corresponds to one line in your plot. E. g. the first line consists of the points (69120/40859/258), (69219/40860/255) and (69319/40862/228) in (X/Y/Z) representation.

Comment: I have tried somethings like that and the result is not correct :/ http://puu.sh/vUTDm/dd2c49bf97.jpg